# Convert YYYY-MMM-DD to date in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a flat file with a date field in the format YYYY-MMM-DD HH24:MM:SS :

```
2015-Apr-09 06:57:21.980549
```

I would like to load it as a datetime in my table, any idea about how to do this conversion ?

I'm using SSIS 2014

Comment: show what you have tried.

Comment: I've tried make the field as a dbtime2 in the flat file connection manager and the convert component, both are not working

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that silly MMM part.

To get rid of it without resorting to a .net script, add a derived column with the following formula:

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(testdate,"Jan","01"),"Feb","02"),"Mar","03"),"Apr","04"),"May","05"),"Jun","06"),"Jul","07"),"Aug","08"),"Sep","09"),"Oct","10"),"Nov","11"),"Dec","12")
```

Then, pipe the resulting column to a Data Conversion, and set the target type to DB_DBTIMESTAMP2 with precision 7 (so as to not lose data precision) or set it to DB_DBTIMESTAMP if precision loss is acceptable.

The latter should implicitly convert to DATE, but if not, you will need to explicitly perform another conversion.

Answer (score -1):

A flexible and fast way to do that is:

**Step 1**: Add a Derived Column Transformation module into your flow of data: 
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7399.ssis-derived-column-transformation.aspx

Using this approach you are flexible at modifications - you can construct your date column from multiple columns, for example:

**Step 2**: In the "Expression" filed of your transformation you must use a CAST like this: 
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP2, 4) [YourColumn] :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141704.aspx

If your column is not in the correct format (date-month-etc...), you can use the substring function to put the string in the right order/format:

SUBSTRING (SSIS Expression) - Returns a part of a character expression.